# Use of series and integral (Fourier or not) to write solution of three dimensional wave equation in different coordinates systems

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, wave-equation

Consider wave equation in three dimensions
$$\square f=0$$
Consider first cartesian coordinates.
With separation of variables one can find an infinite number of indipendent solutions

$$f_{\omega,\alpha,\beta,\gamma}(x,y,z,t)=f^{0}_{\omega,\alpha,\beta,\gamma}e^{i(\alpha x+\beta y+ \gamma z-\omega t)}\tag{1}$$

To get the general solution it is necessary to write the linear combination

$$f(x,y,z,t)=\sum_{\omega,\alpha,\beta,\gamma}f^{0}_{\omega,\alpha,\beta,\gamma}e^{i(\alpha x+\beta y+ \gamma z-\omega t)}\tag{2}$$

On textbook is it claimed that $(2)$ is a Fourier series, as long as $f$ is periodic. It is not explicit but I suppose that values of $\omega,\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ considered in $(2)$ must be a multiple of a foundamental value $\omega_0,\alpha_0,\beta_0,\gamma_0$. Is that correct?

---

If $f$ is not periodic, then it is necessary to use an integral. What is the form of the integral rapresentation of $f$ in this case and what is its Fourier trasform? My guess is:

$$f(x,y,z,t)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{\frac{4}{2}}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(\omega,\alpha,\beta,\gamma)e^{i(\alpha x+\beta y+ \gamma z-\omega t)} d\omega  \,\,d\alpha \,\, d\beta \,\,d \gamma$$

$$F(\omega,\alpha,\beta,\gamma)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{\frac{4}{2}}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,y,z,t)e^{-i(\alpha x+\beta y+ \gamma z-\omega t)} dx\,\,dy \,\, dz \,\,d t$$

Are  these the correct expressions?

---

---

If I go in cylindrical coordinates for istance, the solution is

$$f(r,\phi , z,t) =\sum_{\omega,n,h} R^{0}_{\omega, n, h } H_n\Bigg(r \sqrt{\frac{\omega^2}{c^2}-h^2}\Bigg) e^{i(n\phi +hz-\omega t)} \tag{3}$$

Is $(3)$ still a Fourier series? There is an Hankel function $H$ that contains $r$ but also $\omega$ and $h$ (and its order is $n$), so it should not be a Fourier series but then what "kind" of series is $(3)$?

In particular supposing $f(r,\phi , z,t) =R(r) \Phi(\phi) Z(z) \chi (t)$ can I factorize $(2)$ as a Fourier series for  $\Phi(\phi) Z(z) \chi (t)$ and a Fourier-Bessel series for $R(r)$?

Finally if $f$ is not periodic and I'm using cylindrical coordinates, is $(3)$ subsituted by something else (on textbook there are no explicit assumption for $(3)$, i.e. periodicity)?

(I have similar doubts for solution in spherical coordinates)

Comment: For part 1), you are missing an important piece: in order to be a solution, there is an algebraic relationship between $\omega,$ $\alpha,$ $\beta,$ and $\gamma$ that must hold. So at the end of the day there are three sums/integrals, not four. In the case where there are boundary conditions on some compact boundary or you are looking for periodic solutions, it is true that it is a discrete sum rather than an integral. You can use the boundary conditions or the periodicity constraint to find the allowed modes.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thanks for the comment! I'm ok with the dependence of $\omega^2/c^2=\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2$ but I do not see why there should be only three integrals, for example in two dimensions here http://sepwww.stanford.edu/sep/prof/pvi/dft/paper_html/node18.html there are three integrals (2 space+1 time). Could you say something more specific about it?

Comment: I don't understand what your link shows... it's just about Fourier transforms. If the four obey an equation, how can there be four independent sums over them? The fourth needs to come along for the ride with the other three. Search "eigenmode expansion" or "separation of variables". The solution method is given in many places.